# How to calculate the distance between object and camera, knowing the pixels occupied by the object in an image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

**By using the segmentation I am able to find the number of pixels occupied by an object in an image. Now I need to kind the distance by using the pixels occupied.**

- object real dimensions (H x W) = 11 x 5.5 cm.
- The object is placed at 50 cm distance pixels occupied are = 42894
- The object is placed at 60 cm distance pixels occupied are = 31269.
- The total pixel in an image = 480 x 640  = 307200.

**what is the distance if the image occupies 22323 pixels ???**

Comment: I think you are confusing this community with a calculator. Please get some basic maths knowledge befor you do any programming or image-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance to the object is 67.7cm

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model

Image size is inversely proportional to the distance. Repeat your experiement for a few distances and plot a size vs distance to see for yourself.

Of course this is a simplyfied model that only works for a fixed focal length.